# Upload automatically html files

Tags: uploads, html

I have about 1400 html files and I want to upload them in a wordpress site where I am administrator. I want to publish them as blog posts.
How can I achieve that automatically?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? For example, what are you trying to achieve with the html files?

Comment: If you actually want to upload them, you should use an FTP client, if you have FTP credentials. If you want to publish them as pages or blog posts, that's another story.

Comment: I want to publish them as blog posts.

Comment: Do the HTML files contain only the post content, or do they include things like header, footer, navigation? If they're stripped down to only the HTML you would want inside the post content itself, you could write a script to open, read, and publish a post for each one, or you can look into import plugins - not sure if any exist for straight HTML, you might have to pull them into a CSV with more details such as the post title which is also required.

Comment: HTML files contain only the post content, is there a plug in? If not is it possible to write a script? I'm new in wordpress I know programming but I don't know how write code in wordpress

Comment: If you are familiar with SQL, you can turn every HTML file into an `INSERT` statement that will insert the file into the `posts` table as the `post_contents` field, with appriopriate defaults for other fields like `post_author`, `post_title` etc.

Comment: You'll probably need to write a script for that, none of the no code importers are going to handle that level of complexity.  I would suggest using something like [WP Utility Script Runner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-utility-script-runner/) for that

Comment: Loop through all the files, grab content and add it to a new post using[`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

Comment: Or, if this isn't something you're going to be reusing ever, it might be more cost effective to hire someone on fiverr for a few bucks to just manually copy pasta everything for you.

Comment: @mrben522 I think I will use wp_insert_post thank you. To read content of html file can I use 
file_get_contents ?

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp

Comment: @asv yeah `file_get_contents` is how you should get the content of the files.  you can use [`scandir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get a list of all the files in your directory

Comment: @mrben522 Thank you, I must install the program written in php like a plugin or is there a way to create a kind of macro in wordpress? In this case where I can find a good reference to insert a plugin

Comment: check out the WP Utility Script Runner link I posted earlier.  You can write the script for that in PHP, FTP it into a utilities folder in your theme and run it with that plugin.  there's an example script in the plugin files you can check out to see how it works

Comment: @mrben522 Ok, thank you very much.